# Expected product of two numbers with and without replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$, you draw two numbers with replacement and compute the product. Also, you draw two numbers without replacement and compute the product.

- Using basic arithmetic/reasoning (don't explicitly compute the expected values), which would you expect to have a larger value?
- Find the expectation of both products.

---

For the first part, I really don't have great reasoning. I know that if we consider the problem with replacement, then we're adding $10$ more outcomes (i.e. the outcomes in which we pick the same number twice), and the average outcome we're adding would have expected value $(1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 10^2)/10 = 38.5$,  but I don't really see how I can get a comparison going on here.

As for computation, I was able to compute the expected value with replacement to be $5.5^2 = 30.25$ since both draws are independent and we'd expect each draw to be $5.5$ (so just multiply the expectations).

I'm not entirely sure how to compute the expectation without replacement. I thought about conditioning on the first number that we picked, like this:

$$\mathbb{E}[XY] = \sum_{x = 1}^{10} \mathbb{E}[XY \mid X = x] P(X = x) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{x = 1}^{10} \mathbb{E}[XY \mid X = x].$$

Now to compute $\mathbb{E}[XY \mid X = x]$, I just made the observation that $Y$ needs to equal some value between $1$ and $10$ but not $x$. We can just include all numbers and subtract the case in which we have $x$ for both to find $E(XY \mid X = x) = (x + 2x + 3x + \cdots + 10x - x^2)/9 = (55 - x^2)/9,$ so

$$\mathbb{E}[XY] = \frac{1}{90}\cdot \sum_{x = 1}^{10}55 - x^2 = \frac{165}{90},$$

but this clearly seems off. Can someone help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all outcomes in the with-replacement case is $(1+2+\cdots+10)^2=3025$. The sum of the outcomes on the diagonal, not allowed in the without-replacement case, is $1^2+2^2+\cdots+10^2=385$. Now subtract $385$ from $3025$ to get the sum of all possibilities in the without-replacement case, $2640$, and divide by $90$ (the number of possiblities) to get the answer for the without-replacement case of $\frac{88}3$.

Comment: @fda I suppose the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality could be that intuition.